# View vector GeoServer line layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, line, visualisation

I have simple line layer created based on shapefiles. It can be viewed in GeoServer with OpenLayers preview:

[image]

I also can be imported and correctly viewed in QGIS.

I tried to visualize this layer over OSM map in my leaflet:

```js
var map = L.map('map',
);
map.setView([35.6, 25], 8);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);
var WMSe = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/geoserver/wms";

var OHLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(WMSe, {
    layers: 'fch:OHL-fch',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    format_options: 'layout:message',
    attribution: "Algum texto de teste",
    layout: 'message',
}).addTo(map)
```

where `fch:OHL-fch` in name of layer in layer preview in GeoServer.
When I run this, all I get is OSM map without line layer.
Any help in resolving this is appreciable.

Geoserver preview request:

```
http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/geoserver/fch/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=fch%3AOHL-fch&bbox=23.6974544525146%2C35.0042533874512%2C26.1459541320801%2C35.4908332824707&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A4326&styles=&format=application/openlayers
```

leaflet request(NOT working):

```
URL: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=%20fch%3AOHL-fch&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&format_options=layout%3Amessage&layout=message&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2191602.4749925733,4226661.916057106,2348145.5089206146,4383204.949985149
```

leaflet request(working):

```
URL: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxy:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=%20fch%3AOHL-fch&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&format_options=layout%3Amessage&layout=message&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2817774.6107047372,3913575.848201024,2974317.644632778,4070118.8821290666
```

Print of leaflet layer:

```
_container: <div class="leaflet-layer ">
_crs: {latLngToPoint: function, pointToLatLng: function, project: function, unproject: function, scale: function, …}
_events: {remove: Array}
_fadeFrame: 163
_globalTileRange: {min: Object, max: Object, extend: function, getCenter: function, getBottomLeft: function, …}
_initHooksCalled: true
_leaflet_id: 83
_level: {el: <div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated">, origin: Object, zoom: 8}
_levels: {8: Object}
_loading: false
_map: e {options: Object, _container: <div id="map">, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, _fadeAnimated: true, …}
_mapToAdd: e {options: Object, _container: <div id="map">, _leaflet_id: 2, _containerId: 3, _fadeAnimated: true, …}
_noPrune: false
_onMove: function()
_tileSize: {x: 256, y: 256, clone: function, add: function, _add: function, …}
_tileZoom: 8
_tiles: {145:100:8: Object, 145:101:8: Object, 144:100:8: Object, 146:100:8: Object, 144:101:8: Object, …}
_url: "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/geoserver/wms"
_wmsVersion: 1.1
_wrapX: [0, 256] (2)
_wrapY: undefined
_zoomAnimated: true
options: {layers: "fch:OHL-fch", format: "image/png", transparent: true, format_options: "layout:message", attribution: "Algum texto de teste", …}
wmsParams: {service: "WMS", request: "GetMap", layers: "fch:OHL-fch", styles: "", format: "image/png", …}
```

Comment: is there any data actually returned by the request? Does it work for other formats?

Comment: What does the WMS request generated by Leaflet look like compared with the request in Geoserver preview? What is the CRS of the layer?

Comment: Is that blank space at `' fch:OHL-fch'` intended?

Comment: @IvanSanchez its a typo. I shortened layer name when copying code due to privacy. I have edited it in text above. Anyway not working with original name.

Comment: @TomazicM Added link from WMS request from Geoserver. Not sure how to view Leaflet request? I have added print out of entire layer to code. If you need any particular data I can print it out. CRS of layer is WGS84 - EPSG:4326.

Comment: @IanTurton Tried with image/jpeg, not working. I have added printout of layer and geoserrver request.

Comment: Default CRS for Leaflet maps is Web Mercator (EPSG:3857), so your Geoserver layer should also be in that CRS, or you have to set Leaflet map CRS to EPSG:4326, but then your base layer has also to be in that CRS.

Comment: It looks like everything is fine with projection. I tried uploading same layer to different server with already running geoserver and it worked. I even turned of firewall but no succees so far.

Comment: I figured out to find leaflet request and added one working and one not working request in original question. There is a difference in projection bounding box, maybe projection in not working geoserver need to be set.

Comment: Where did you get working Leaflet request from?

Comment: @TomazicM from another linux machine with installed geoserver

Comment: In leaflet you have request in 3857, please check if you publish this layer in this projection. Like @TomazicM mention before

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out what was the problem. Part of leaflet request:

```
format_options: 'layout:message',
//attribution: "Algum texto de teste",
layout: 'message'
```

was calling for layout:message WMS decorator which wasn't declared in Geoserver settings.
Hence, after removing these from leaflet request, everything worked fine.